# Publishing partially enabled Add-Ons In Google Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We are currently developing GMAIL addons in our company.

My question is very simple. Does the google apps marketplace allow the publication of Partially Enabled add-ons?

We were thinking of using a service like LaunchDarkly to be able to turn some features on and off for some or all of our clients.

Thank you very much.

PS : Partially enabled addons, operate only with say 40-60 percent of their functionality upon download. If a corresponding feature flag is activated on our end or in a service like LaunchDarkly, they will be 100% operational (or feature complete).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *partially enabled add-ons*? @GovZ

Comment: thanks @ale13. I have updated the question I raised. I hope that clarifies the question? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the functionalities you want to enable and the type of add-on you have, you might be able to make use of [Editor add-ons triggers](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers) or [Workspace add-ons triggers](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-triggers) and limit the interactions based on these.

However, an add-on must be **fully functional** before it is published.

#### Reference

- [Publish an Add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview);
- [Editor Add-on Triggers](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers);
- [Google Workspace Add-on Triggers](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-triggers).